# Faster shuffle for a large numpy memmap array

Tags: python, numpy, mmap

I have a large(35GB) numpy memmap array.

What are some ways that I can do to shuffle faster than np.random.shuffle?

### Background & more information

I am working on a project that utilizes machine learning methods. I am experimenting with shuffled input to see if it will improve my model. The form of my train dataset is 111222333444(label), while the testing dataset is usually something like 2234331122(label).

For the attempts on "better way", I've tried sorting the test dataset, but it takes too much time (sort, test, back to original form). In ML, time for testing a model is far more important than training a model.

I have tried random sampling, and it does the job faster than shuffling. Shuffling takes about 4 hours, random sampling overhead takes about 3.5 hours. The reason I am going for shuffling is that my model has to be run on a GPU server, and I share the GPU server with several of my colleagues. Shuffling is not GPU intensive, so I can do that on my personal desktop.

I use tensorflow. The input dimension is (450,000 * 4) * 33 * 33 * 4 (N * 90 degree rotation * W * H * channel).

Comment: For the same result? There probably isn't. It's already shuffling in-place. And moving around such an amount of data takes time. But perhaps *why* you want to do that is worth considering. Isn't there a better way for you to accomplish whatever purpose you have?

Comment: You might want to take random samples of this array instead of shuffling it.

Comment: @spectras I am working on a project that utilizes machine learning methods. I am experimenting with shuffled input to see if it will improve my model. The form of my train dataset is 111222333444, while the testing dataset is usually something like 2234331122.

Comment: @spectras For the attempts on "better way", I've tried sorting the test dataset, but it takes too much time (sort, test, back to original form). In ML, time for testing a model is far more important than training a model.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz I have tried random sampling, and it does the job faster than shuffling. Shuffling takes about 4 hours, random sampling overhead takes about 3.5 hours. The reason I am going for shuffling is that my model has to be run on a GPU server, and I share the GPU server with several of my colleagues. Shuffling is not GPU intensive, so I can do that on my personal desktop.